# How I hash new passed password with updateUser(rabbitmq)?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, nestjs

well, I can hash my passoword in createUser, However, to update a user, I need to hash this new passed password, but when I have data.senha: senhaHasheada or usuarioachar.senha: senhaHasheada, I can't implement it before saving, it says it is invalid, when I create a const destructuring the updateUsuarioDTO with {id, nome, senha, email, idade} = dados, it doesn't work because I need to pass an id parameter to search for the user to update it, if I have another id: string parameter, it says that the id was duplicated if I have the unstructured dados in the second parameter.

my auth(rabbirtmq) service(update User):

```
 async atualizarUsuario(dados: atualizarUsuarioDTO){
    const {id, nome, email, senha, idade} = dados
    const usuarioachar  = await this.usuarioRepository.findOneBy({id})
    
    if(usuarioachar === null){
      throw new NotFoundException('úsuario com id nao achado')
    }
    const senhaHasheada = await this.hashearSenha(senha)
  
    
    const usuario = this.usuarioRepository.save({nome, email, senha: senhaHasheada, idade })
    console.log(senha)
    return usuario
  }
```

my controler:

```
 @MessagePattern({ cmd: 'atualizar-usuario'})
  async atualizarUsuario(@Ctx() contexto: RmqContext,@Payload() {id, ...dados}: atualizarUsuarioDTO){
    const channel = contexto.getChannelRef()
    const message = contexto.getMessage()
    channel.ack(message)
    return this.authService.atualizarUsuario({id, ...dados})
```

my createUser(I can hash the password, I want something similar):

```
async criarUsuario(dados: CriaUsuarioDTO): Promise<UsuarioEntidade>{
    const {id, nome, email, senha, idade } = dados

    const achado = await this.acharEmail(email)
    if(achado){
      throw new ConflictException('Usuario ja existente com esse email')
    }
    const senhaHasheada = await this.hashearSenha(senha)

    const usuarioSalvar = await this.usuarioRepository.save({
      id, nome, email, senha: senhaHasheada, idade
    })
    return usuarioSalvar
  }
```

my api gateway controler:

```
@Put('usuario/:id')
  async atualizaUsuario(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() data: atualizarUsuarioDTO){
    return this.authServico.send(
      {
        cmd: 'atualizar-usuario'
      },
      {id, data}
    )
  }
```

my hash async function(hashearSenha):

```
async hashearSenha(senha: string){
    const sal = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    const hash =  bcrypt.hash(senha, sal)
    return hash
  }
```

obs: the word senha is password.

obs2: when I try like dados.senha = senhaHasheda it gives a error saying this:

```
 ERROR [RpcExceptionsHandler] data and salt arguments required
```

Comment: Have you verified you're actually passing `senha` where you think you are and it is populated? That would be my initial guess as to what's going on here. Also, `hash` is an async method, you should `await` it

Comment: i change somethings and add my gateway controler(update message), you think this is better?, maybe in the controler the {id, ...dados } is causing this, but If I remove the {}, it says that 3 arguments were passed and the maximum is 2.

Comment: Try `{ id, ...data }` in your `PUT` request rather than `{ id, data }`

Comment: worked, but when I update this object with this id, let's assume that the 1st database id, when I update it, it comes to the last ones, as if I had created a new object but with the same id, its normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `{ id, data }` the payload sent to your microservice server should be `{ id, ...data }`. As for why it comes back as a new entry instead of an update, I'd assume that's something TypeORM is doing under the hood. You can try using an `update` method instead of `save`, or possibly run a `findOne` by id first, if you prefer that approach.